# Flash-накопитель

Tags: лексика

Является ли теперь слово **"флешка"** нормативной формой?
В настоящем времени слово "flash-накопитель" используется все реже и реже.

Answer (score 4):

Довольно трудно судить, являются ли какие-то слова, не так давно вошедшие в русский язык, нормативными. Дело в том, что словари составляются не так уж и часто, да и самим авторам трудно сказать, к какому виду отнести слово: к разговорному, сленговому или вполне себе нормативному. 
Само происхождение этого слова заставляет задуматься, может ли оно полноценно заменить *"flash-накопитель"*. Исконное слово хорошо описывает сам предмет, а *"флешка"* не очень, но оно сокращает время на произношение, что характерно для разговорной речи. Я думаю, слово  пока стоит считать именно разговорным.